# Get Seq index from element in Spark Sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe as shown below:

```
---------------------+------------------------
text                 | featured_text
---------------------+------------------------
sun                  | [type, move, sun]
---------------------+------------------------
```

I want to search the "text" column value in "featured_text" Array and get the index of the "text" value if present. In the above example, I want to search for "sun" in Array [type, move, sun] and result will be "2" (index).

Is there any spark sql function/scala function available to get the index from the element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no function to do this directly with the Spark SQL API. However, you can use an [`UDF`](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-udfs.html) instead as follows (I'm assuming the input dataframe is called `df`):

```
val getIndex = udf((text: String, featuredText: Seq[String]) => {
  featuredText.indexOf(text)
})

val df2 = df.withColumn("index", getIndex($"text", $"featured_text"))
```

Which will give:

```
+----+-----------------+-----+
|text|    featured_text|index|
+----+-----------------+-----+
| sun|[type, move, sun]|    2|
+----+-----------------+-----+
```

In the case where the value is not present the index column will have a -1.